# My game keeps crashing after I added the attack code

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So I'm making an battle game and it was going well until I added the functionality of attack. Now it crashes when I run it. I don't know what I did wrong!

I tried to change up the variables for attack and move the if statements around, but nothing worked.

first added section

```
def buttons(x,y):
    if y > -230 and y < -161 and x > 17 and x < 299:
        eHP -= pDMG
        textinput("","attack")
        TurnToken -= 1
    if x > 300 and x < 671 and y > -234 and y < -153:
        textinput("","Coming soon")
    if x > 300 and x < 671 and y < -235 and y > -356:
         textinput("","you can't run during the tutorial!")
    if x > 17 and x < 299 and y < -235 and y > -356:
        if eATK != 1:
            eDMG -= pDEF
            textinput("","defend")
            TurnToken -= 1
        else:
            textinput("","Whoops! looks like the enemy's attack has reached 1 or less! Try something else!")
    print(x,y)
```

second added section

```
while eHP != 0 or pHP != 0:
    if turnToken == 1:
        onscreenclick(buttons ,1)
        listen()
    else:
        turnToken += 1
        AtkDef = randint(1,2)
        if pATK == 1:
            AtkDef == 1
        if AtkDef == 1:
            pHP -= eATK
            textinput("","attack")
        else:
            pATK -= eDEF
            textinput("","defend")
```

I expected the player to be able to attack and defend and the bot to be able to do the same, but instead whenever the 'attack' button is pressed, the game automatically freezes.

here is the full code:

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
import time
import random
penup()
hideturtle()
window = Screen()
wn = window
wn.screensize()
wn.setup(width = 1.0, height = 1.0)
m1 = Turtle()
m1.speed(0)
m1.hideturtle()
m1.fillcolor("lime")
m2 = Turtle()
m2.speed(0)
m2.hideturtle()
m2.fillcolor("red")
txt = Turtle()
txt.speed(0)
txt.pensize(15)
txt.hideturtle()
txt.speed(0)
pHP = 100
pATK = 10
pDEF = 1
eHP = 50
eATK = 10
eDEF = 1
turnToken = 1
def pSlime ():
    m1.begin_poly()
    m1.penup()
    m1.goto(-300,200)
    m1.pendown()
    m1.begin_fill()
    m1.left(180)
    m1.forward(180)
    m1.circle(20,90)
    m1.forward(360)
    m1.circle(20,90)
    m1.forward(360)
    m1.circle(20,90)
    m1.forward(360)
    m1.circle(20,90)
    m1.forward(180)
    m1.end_fill()
    m1.fillcolor("black")
    m1.penup()
    m1.goto(-350,100)
    m1.pendown()
    m1.begin_fill()
    m1.forward(20)
    m1.right(90)
    m1.forward(20)
    m1.right(90)
    m1.forward(20)
    m1.right(90)
    m1.forward(20)
    m1.end_fill()
    m1.left(90)
    m1.penup()
    m1.goto(-250,120)
    m1.pendown()
    m1.begin_fill()
    m1.forward(20)
    m1.right(90)
    m1.forward(20)
    m1.right(90)
    m1.forward(20)
    m1.right(90)
    m1.forward(20)
    m1.end_fill()
    m1.penup()
    m1.goto(-400,0)
    m1.pendown()
    m1.begin_fill()
    m1.forward(20)
    m1.right(90)
    m1.forward(100)
    m1.right(90)
    m1.forward(20)
    m1.right(90)
    m1.forward(100)
    m1.end_fill()
    m1.end_poly()
def fireSlime ():
    m2.begin_poly()
    m2.penup()
    #m2.goto(-300,200)
    m2.pendown()
    m2.begin_fill()
    m2.left(180)
    m2.forward(180)
    m2.circle(20,90)
    m2.forward(360)
    m2.circle(20,90)
    m2.forward(360)
    m2.circle(20,90)
    m2.forward(360)
    m2.circle(20,90)
    m2.forward(180)
    m2.end_fill()
    m2.fillcolor("black")
    m2.penup()
    m2.goto(-350 +550,100 +150)
    m2.pendown()
    m2.begin_fill()
    m2.forward(20)
    m2.right(90)
    m2.forward(20)
    m2.right(90)
    m2.forward(20)
    m2.right(90)
    m2.forward(20)
    m2.end_fill()
    m2.left(90)
    m2.penup()
    m2.goto(-250 + 550,120 + 150)
    m2.pendown()
    m2.begin_fill()
    m2.forward(20)
    m2.right(90)
    m2.forward(20)
    m2.right(90)
    m2.forward(20)
    m2.right(90)
    m2.forward(20)
    m2.end_fill()
    m2.penup()
    m2.goto(-400 + 650,150)
    m2.pendown()
    m2.begin_fill()
    m2.forward(20)
    m2.right(90)
    m2.forward(100)
    m2.right(90)
    m2.forward(20)
    m2.right(90)
    m2.forward(100)
    m2.end_fill()
    m2.end_poly()
def buttons(x,y):
    if y > -230 and y < -161 and x > 17 and x < 299:
        eHP -= pDMG
        textinput("","attack")
        TurnToken -= 1
    if x > 300 and x < 671 and y > -234 and y < -153:
        textinput("","Coming soon")
    if x > 300 and x < 671 and y < -235 and y > -356:
         textinput("","you can't run during the tutorial!")
    if x > 17 and x < 299 and y < -235 and y > -356:
        if eATK != 1:
            eDMG -= pDEF
            textinput("","defend")
            TurnToken -= 1
        else:
            textinput("","Whoops! looks like the enemy's attack has reached 1 or less! Try something else!")
    print(x,y)
pSlime()
txt.penup()
txt.goto(-800, -230)
txt.pendown()
txt.forward(750)
txt.left(50)
txt.forward(100)
txt.right(50)
txt.forward(800)
txt.penup()
txt.goto(-800, 230)
txt.pendown()
txt.pensize(5)
txt.forward(700)
txt.left(90)
txt.forward(200)
txt.left(90)
txt.penup()
txt.forward(570)
txt.left(90)
txt.forward(105)
txt.write("\nWelcome to Evolve, a game of monsters, genetics, \nand battle. The slime on the left will be your first monster.\n Click the attack button to attack the fire slime on the right", align="left", font=("Agency FB", 15, "bold"))
txt.penup()
txt.forward(20)
txt.goto(300,300)
txt.pensize(3)
txt.forward(450)
txt.pendown()
txt.forward(85)
txt.left(90)
txt.forward(500)
txt.left(180)
txt.forward(900)
txt.left(90)
txt.forward(200)
txt.left(180)
txt.forward(200)
txt.left(90)
txt.right(180)
txt.forward(362)
txt.right(90)
txt.forward(200)
txt.up()
m2.up()
m2.goto(300,350)
m2.down()
fireSlime()
txt.goto(110,-220)
txt.write("Attack ", align="left", font=("Agency FB", 40, "bold"))
txt.forward(100)
txt.write("Defend ", align="left", font=("Agency FB", 40, "bold"))
txt.left(90)
txt.forward(200)
txt.write("Exit Battle ", align="left", font=("Agency FB", 40, "bold"))
txt.left(90)
txt.forward(100)
txt.write("Item ", align="left", font=("Agency FB", 40, "bold"))
while eHP != 0 or pHP != 0:
    if turnToken == 1:
        onscreenclick(buttons ,1)
        listen()
    else:
        turnToken += 1
        AtkDef = randint(1,2)
        if pATK == 1:
            AtkDef == 1
        if AtkDef == 1:
            pHP -= eATK
            textinput("","attack")
        else:
            pATK -= eDEF
            textinput("","defend")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it was going well until I added the functionality of attack. Now it
>   crashes when I run it. I don't know what I did wrong!

This code has a number of issues, some of which a good syntax checker should have warned you about:  Your use of `randint()` isn't qualified by the module name:

```
import random
AtkDef = randint(1,2)
```

either:

```
import random
AtkDef = random.randint(1,2)
```

or:

```
from random import randint
AtkDef = randint(1,2)
```

You've a syntax error in this variable assignment:

```
if pATK == 1:
    AtkDef == 1  # should be "=" not "=="
```

The variables `pDMG` and `eDMG` are never defined anywhere.

The variable `turnToken` also goes by the name `TurnToken` at various places in the code.

The global variables `turnToken` and `eHP` are modified in `buttons()` and so must be declared:

```
def buttons(x, y):
    global turnToken, eHP
```

These calls aren't doing anything for you so you can remove them:

```
m1.begin_poly()
m1.end_poly()
m2.begin_poly()
m2.end_poly()
```

Finally, your main loop works against the event nature of turtle and should be recast as a timer event.

Below I've patched and reworked your code as best I could -- I may have introduced new bugs in process, but it now basically runs:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

LARGE_FONT = ("Agency FB", 40, "bold")
SMALL_FONT = ("Agency FB", 15, "bold")

def pSlime():
    m1.penup()
    m1.goto(-480, 200)
    m1.left(180)
    m1.pendown()

    m1.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        m1.circle(20, 90)
        m1.forward(360)
    m1.end_fill()

    m1.penup()
    m1.goto(-350, 100)
    m1.pendown()
    m1.fillcolor("black")

    m1.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        m1.forward(20)
        m1.right(90)
    m1.end_fill()

    m1.penup()
    m1.goto(-250, 120)
    m1.left(180)
    m1.pendown()

    m1.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        m1.forward(20)
        m1.right(90)
    m1.end_fill()

    m1.left(90)
    m1.penup()
    m1.goto(-400, 0)
    m1.pendown()

    m1.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(2):
        m1.forward(20)
        m1.right(90)
        m1.forward(100)
        m1.right(90)
    m1.end_fill()

def fireSlime():
    m2.penup()
    m2.goto(120, 350)
    m2.left(180)
    m2.pendown()

    m2.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        m2.circle(20, 90)
        m2.forward(360)
    m2.end_fill()

    m2.penup()
    m2.goto(550 - 350, 100 + 150)
    m2.pendown()
    m2.fillcolor("black")

    m2.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        m2.forward(20)
        m2.right(90)
    m2.end_fill()

    m2.penup()
    m2.goto(550 - 250, 120 + 150)
    m2.left(180)
    m2.pendown()

    m2.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        m2.forward(20)
        m2.right(90)
    m2.end_fill()

    m2.penup()
    m2.goto(650 - 400, 150)
    m2.left(90)
    m2.pendown()

    m2.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(2):
        m2.forward(20)
        m2.right(90)
        m2.forward(100)
        m2.right(90)
    m2.end_fill()

def buttons(x, y):
    global turnToken, eHP

    if 17 < x < 299 and y -230 < y < -161:
        eHP -= pDMG
        screen.textinput("", "attack")
        turnToken -= 1
    if 300 < x < 671 and -234 < y < -153:
        screen.textinput("", "Coming soon")
    if 300 < x < 671 and -356 < y < -235:
        screen.textinput("", "You can't run during the tutorial!")
    if 17 < x < 299 and -356 < y < -235:
        if eATK != 1:
            eDMG -= pDEF
            screen.textinput("", "defend")
            turnToken -= 1
        else:
            screen.textinput("", "Whoops! looks like the enemy's attack has reached 1 or less! Try something else!")

def play():
    global turnToken

    pHP = 100
    pATK = 10

    if eHP != 0 or pHP != 0:
        if turnToken == 1:
            screen.onscreenclick(buttons, 1)
        else:
            screen.onscreenclick(None, 1)

            turnToken += 1

            AtkDef = randint(1, 2)
            if pATK == 1:
                AtkDef = 1

            if AtkDef == 1:
                pHP -= eATK
                screen.textinput("", "attack")
            else:
                pATK -= eDEF
                screen.textinput("", "defend")

        screen.ontimer(play, 1000)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)

m1 = Turtle(visible=False)
m1.speed('fastest')
m1.fillcolor("lime")

m2 = Turtle(visible=False)
m2.speed('fastest')
m2.fillcolor("red")

txt = Turtle(visible=False)
txt.speed('fastest')
txt.penup()

pDEF = 1
eDEF = 1

pDMG = 5
eDMG = 5

eHP = 50
eATK = 10

turnToken = 1

pSlime()

fireSlime()

txt.pensize(15)
txt.goto(-800, -230)
txt.pendown()

txt.forward(750)
txt.left(50)
txt.forward(100)
txt.right(50)
txt.forward(800)

txt.penup()
txt.pensize(5)
txt.goto(-800, 230)
txt.pendown()

txt.forward(700)
txt.left(90)
txt.forward(200)
txt.left(90)

txt.penup()
txt.forward(570)
txt.left(90)
txt.forward(105)

txt.write("\nWelcome to Evolve, a game of monsters, genetics, \nand battle. The slime on the left will be your first monster.\n Click the attack button to attack the fire slime on the right", align="left", font=SMALL_FONT)

txt.pensize(3)
txt.goto(300, 300)
txt.forward(450)
txt.pendown()

txt.forward(85)
txt.left(90)
txt.forward(500)
txt.left(180)
txt.forward(900)
txt.left(90)
txt.forward(200)
txt.left(180)
txt.forward(200)
txt.left(90)
txt.right(180)
txt.forward(362)
txt.right(90)
txt.forward(200)

txt.penup()
txt.goto(110, -220)
txt.write("Attack", align="left", font=LARGE_FONT)
txt.forward(100)
txt.write("Defend", align="left", font=LARGE_FONT)
txt.left(90)
txt.forward(200)
txt.write("Exit Battle", align="left", font=LARGE_FONT)
txt.left(90)
txt.forward(100)
txt.write("Item", align="left", font=LARGE_FONT)

screen.listen()  # only needs to be called once, can't be undone

play()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I added the full code so it might make more sense now, because I defined them earlier in the code.

Comment: @Fireye, it confirms what I wrote, `TurnToken` and `eHP` are globals that are being treated as locals in `buttons()` due to a lack of a `global` declaration.  Now I also see that `eDMG -= pDEF`  in `buttons()` is a syntax error  as `eDMG` is never defined.

Comment: @Fireye, I've rewritten my answer based on your full code.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons others state, it's not possible to know for sure what your problem since you don't provide all of your code.  I see something suspicious that I'll point out because it very well could be your problem...

Your second block of code is a loop, hence the opportunity for a freeze.  The only way out of that loop is for both 'eHP' and 'pHP' to become 0.  From the code I can see, it's quite likely that this condition will never occur and you'll be stuck in that loop forever.

Not seeing more of your code, I can't know this for sure, but it's quite suspicious that you only ever do a subtraction on the two variables you're testing.  I don't know where the values you're subtracting out come from, but if they're both positive, then you could easily have either of the values you're testing go negative and have no way to ever get out of your loop by getting them both back to 0.

Maybe you want to be testing those values for '< 0' rather than '!= 0' and maybe you want 'and' rather than 'or'.  It's impossible to know with what you've provided.